# XPath query to match two attributes but return only one

Tags: xml, xpath

I need an XPath query that only returns me the id of 'Product A'. No position tags please, I have a huge xml.

```
 //Entities/Entity[@Type="defect"]/Fields/Field[@Name="project"]/Value[.="Product
 A"]
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Entities TotalResults="234">
    <Entity Type="defect">
        <Fields>
            <Field Name="id">
                <Value>272</Value>
                </Field>
            <Field Name="project">
                <Value>Product A</Value>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
    </Entity>
    <Entity Type="defect">
        <Fields>
            <Field Name="id">
                <Value>2829</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="project">
                <Value>Product B</Value>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
    </Entity>
</Entities>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. `[]` are conditions for the preceding location path. So the expression for the id field values of all defects is:

`/Entities/Entity[@Type="defect"]/Fields/Field[@Name="id"]/Value`

If you extend the condition you can limit the result further:

```
/Entities/Entity[
  @Type="defect" and (Fields/Field[@Name = "project"]/Value = "Product A")
]/Fields/Field[@Name="id"]/Value
```